# Spring Boot oauth2: How to set the resource parameter in the authorization request to make adfs happy?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, adfs3.0

I'm trying to set up a spring boot app that uses oauth2 with Active Directory Federation Services as the authentication provider.  I started with the tutorial here...

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

... and got the facebook example to work.  Then, I started adapting it to work with ADFS.  It is close to working, but ADFS expects a resource parameter to be passed with the authorization request and I can't figure out how to set it.  Here's what I've got so far in the config...

```html
security:
    oauth2:
        client:
            clientId: spring-boot-test-client
            userAuthorizationUri: https://domain/adfs/oauth2/authorize
            access-token-uri: https://domain/adfs/oauth2/token
            tokenName: code
            authenticationScheme: query
            clientAuthenticationScheme: form
            grant-type: authorization_code
```

When I click the login link, it redirects to https://domain/adfs/oauth2/authorize?client_id=spring-boot-test-client&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login&response_type=code&state=rjzfyZ

I've tried setting the security:oauth2:client:id, the security:oauth2:client:resourceids and the security:oauth2:resource:id, but none of those seemed to affect the first redirect.  Any idea what I should set to get the resource included in that first redirect?

Answer (score 6):

Answering my own question here... It may be a hack, but I just appended the resource to the userAuthorizationUri

```html
security:
    oauth2:
        client:
            clientId: spring-boot-test-client
            userAuthorizationUri: https://domain/adfs/oauth2/authorize?resource=RelyingPartyTrustIdentifier
            access-token-uri: https://domain/adfs/oauth2/token
            tokenName: code
            authenticationScheme: query
            clientAuthenticationScheme: form
            grant-type: authorization_code
```

Now, I'm getting the login form.

Comment: Did you use ADFS as the identity provider?