# Spring Oauth2 using ADFS Authorization Provider

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2, adfs3.0

I was given a spike to figure out how to use ADFS 3.0 Oauth2 as the authorization provider for a spring application. I have been able to get it to work by using the Spring Oauth2 example then basically hacking a UserInfoTokenServices by creating a JWT parser to extract the authorization out of it.

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

[Spring Boot oauth2: How to set the resource parameter in the authorization request to make adfs happy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39055971/spring-boot-oauth2-how-to-set-the-resource-parameter-in-the-authorization-reque)

[How to configure spring boot security OAuth2 for ADFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43148552/how-to-configure-spring-boot-security-oauth2-for-adfs)

Is there a reason why using ADFS Oauth2 and Spring Oauth2 hasn't been developed together yet? Am I missing something? Is this taboo? If not is there a better way?

Comment: Hi @millsofmn, I'm working in some similar, What was the result of your spike?

Comment: @IgnacioOcampo I haven't figured out if it's taboo or not but I just went with it so my application is using spring security and authenticating against Oauth2 fro ADFS

Answer (score 0):

I think that initially Spring Securityt oAuth2 was not designed to work with ADFS server. The proper Java security engine that will easily resolve your problem is [Pac4J](http://www.pac4j.org/) and here there is a [Spring Security Pac4j](https://github.com/pac4j/spring-security-pac4j) library that helps you to integrate your application with OAuth - SAML (ADFS) - CAS - OpenID Connect - HTTP - OpenID - Google App Engine - Kerberos - LDAP - SQL - JWT - MongoDB - CouchDB - IP address - REST API.

[Here](https://github.com/pac4j/spring-security-pac4j-demo) you can find great demo that will show you some authentication mechanisms that can be simply develoiped using Pac4j.